# How do I resolve the following error in my code?

Tags: c++

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    while ((cin >> a))
    {
        if (a == 0)
            break;
        char inp[401];
        cin >> inp;
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i += 1)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < 400; j += a)
            {
                if (inp[j] == '\0')
                    break;

                cout << inp[j] << endl;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;

    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Error is that I get no output when it should be printing the characters stored in inp[j].Please help resolve this problem.
Input:

```
5
toioynnkpheleaigshareconhtomesnlewx
```

Expected Output:

```
theresnoplacelikehomeonasnowynightx
```

Comment: Those loops are rather suspect, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am trying to output every next 10th element and 5th element alternatively of a given string.

Comment: @DiscoDancer could you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: Use a debugger.  This is an excellent candidate to learn to use a debugger.  A lot better than tracing the execution and variables by hand.

Comment: You are not checking for the length of the text that was typed in.  According to the input, there are less than 400 letters typed in, but your loops may go past, *especially if you have not filled the array with '\0' before you input*.

Comment: This would be a good case to use `std::string` rather than a character array.

Comment: Why do you expect it to print every 10th element? When `a = 5` it should print elements 0, 5, 10, 15, ... then 1, 6, 11, 16, ... then 2, 7, 12, 17, .... But your end test in the inner loop is not correct.

Comment: The `while ((cin >> a))` loop is ending immediately. You need to figure out why that is.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very cryptic, just like the problem of decryption you are trying to solve.  The following code produces the expected output for your given input.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    while ((cin>>a))
    {
        if (a == 0)
            break;
        string inp;
        cin >> inp;
        int f = 9,s=1;
        int inc = f;
        for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j  < inp.length() ; )
            {
                cout << inp[j];
                j += inc;
                inc = inc==f?s:f;
            }
            f-=2;
            s+=2;
            inc = f;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```